# A radio box is automatically checked when the program runs - but it shouldn't be

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm writing an application in C# using Visual Studio 2010. All of a sudden the strangest thing has started happening, though.

I have two radio boxes at the top of the window, both are set to `Checked = False`. I have searched everywhere in the code, I see no reason why it would be anything but `False`.

Now, the first of these two boxes (called `Radio1` and `Radio2` respectively) has started being automatically checked when the application is executed. This causes a problem since there is an event associated with the boxes being checked, and now this event runs every time the program is opened (resulting in some serious issues).

Has anybody got any ideas why this box is automatically being checked? As I mentioned, I have looked everywhere through the code just in case I had a `Radio1.Checked = true;` dangling somewhere. But that is not the case.

Comment: It is standard for one radio button in a group to be checked at all times.  Is there some reason you want your radio buttons to behave in a non-standard way?  If your technical reason is the only justification for this then set the Checked property before hooking up the event handler.

Comment: I worked around this behavior by setting each RadioButton.Checked = false in the constructor.

Answer (score 8):

The RadioButton class contains code to ensure that at least one button in the group is checked when one of them gets the focus and the AutoCheck property is set to True.  This implements the standard behavior of radio buttons.  If you want non-standard behavior then you have to set their AutoCheck properties to false and implement the checking yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this as well. I found that setting TabStop to false also seemed to solve this issue.

Comment: That just makes it hard for the user to move the focus to the button.

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter mechanism so that you can override the click method the first time. like this

```
form_load
  {
    counter=0;
   }
private void rb1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (counter == 0)   { counter++;}
        else {
               //Do your stuff
              }
    }
    private void rb2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (counter == 0)   { counter++;}
        else {
               //Do your stuff
              }
    }
```

Hope this is helpfull.

Answer (score -2):

There should be no reason for this to happen unless you are setting the property within the designer or via code. Strange.